# Documenting a wrapped REST response using swagger UI

Tags: java, rest, jersey, swagger, swagger-ui

I have a WidgetDto that I have annotated with swagger UI annotations. The final response wraps a list of WidgetDtos with a layer of metadata (per page 21 of [this](https://github.com/tfredrich/RestApiTutorial.com/raw/master/media/RESTful%20Best%20Practices-v1_2.pdf) RESTful best practices document). For example:

```
{
  "data" : [ 
    {
      "id" : 1234,
      "prop1" : "val1"
      ...
    },
    {
      "id" : 5678,
      "prop1" : "val2"
      ...
    }, 
    ...
  ]
}
```

My java code looks like this:

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@ApiOperation(
        value = "Get all widgets.",
        response = WidgetDto.class
)
@ApiResponses(value = {
        @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "Returns the list of widgets.")
})
public Response getWidgets() {
  List<WidgetDto> widgets;
  ...
  Map<String, Object> responseBody = new HashMap<>();
  responseBody.put("data", widgets);
  return Response.ok(responseBody).build();
}
```

I'd like to reuse this pattern on multiple resources, and I don't want to create list DTOs for every response type. Is there an elegant way to use swagger to document these types of response bodies?

Comment: Could you make a wrapper class that represents a list of `WidgetDto` inside a field `data`?

Comment: @tim_yates yes, but I am hoping there's a reusable solution that wouldn't require me to create specific wrapper classes for each DTO type.

Answer (score 1):

Your metadata is not a part of your resource but it's a part of your resource's representation.

In my case, responses types are '[application/hal+json](http://stateless.co/hal_specification.html)' **and** 'application/json', each of them use a different wrapper with different metadatas.
To solve this problem, I created an extern document to explain these two wrappers and for each of them, how a single resource and a list of resources are represented with metadata.

I think my choice is correct because I separate the resource of its representations (per page 7 'Manipulation of Resources Through Representations' of [this](https://github.com/tfredrich/RestApiTutorial.com/raw/master/media/RESTful%20Best%20Practices-v1_2.pdf) RESTful best practices document)

In your case, you returns a list of WidgetDtos, the layer of metadata is a part of the representation of your resource.

However, you can use a generic class like Resource and Resources used by [spring-hateoas](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-hateoas) :

```
public class Resources<T> implements Iterable<T>  {
    private final Collection<T> content;
    Resources(Iterable<T> content) {
        this.content = new ArrayList<T>();
        for (T element : content) {
            this.content.add(element);
        }
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@ApiOperation(
        value = "Get all widgets.",
        response = WidgetDto.class
)
@ApiResponses(value = {
        @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "Returns the list of widgets.")
})
public Response getWidgets() {
  List<WidgetDto> widgets;
  ...
  return Response.ok(new Resources<WidgetDto>(widgets)).build();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem a few months ago when I was developing a project for school. The solution is to create an envelope and always return it. The envelope will contain a feild "data" which is a generic; so you will be able to bind it to any data type.
Note that even though I used it I later on read that it should be used scarecly (I think your case is a good example of usage) but technically an Exception object should be thrown if the request failed.

Anyway this is my Response class which I used to return all my responses:

```
public class Response <AnyData> {

    private static final String SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String FAILURE = "failure";

    private String status;
    private AnyData data;
    private String error;

    private Response(String status, AnyData data, String error) {
        this.status = status;
        this.data = data;
        this.error = error;;
    }

    private Response(String status, AnyData data) {
        this(status, data,"");
    }

    private Response(String status, String error) {
        this(status, null, error);
    }

    public static <AnyData> Response<AnyData> success(AnyData data) {
        return new Response<AnyData>(SUCCESS, data);
    }

    public static <AnyData> Response<AnyData> failure(String error) {
        return new Response<AnyData>(FAILURE, error);
    }

    public static <AnyData> Response<AnyData> unimplemented() {
        return new Response<AnyData>(FAILURE, "Missing implementation in the backend.");
    }

    public static <AnyData> Response<AnyData> failureUserNotFound() {
        return  Response.failure("User not found!");
    }

    public static <AnyData> Response<AnyData> failureBusinessNotFound() {
        return  Response.failure("Business not found!");
    }

    // Removed getters and setters for simplicity.
}
```

After this is set we will just create the responses right from the Comtroller. I changed it a bit to make it work with the sample is should be legible enough. Note that I have static methods for my responses: 'success()', 'error()'...

```
@RestController
@Api(tags={"Widgets"})
public class WidgetController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/api/widgets", method=RequestMethod.GET, produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @ApiOperation(value = "Get all widgets.")
    @ApiResponses(value = {
            @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "Returns the list of widgets.")
    })
    public Response<List<WidgetDto>> getWidgets() {
      List<WidgetDto> widgets = new LinkedList<>();
      widgets.add(new WidgetDto(1234, "val1"));
      widgets.add(new WidgetDto(5678, "val2"));

      return  Response.success(widgets);
    }
}
```

And here is a sample of the response body:
[image]

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can define the `responseContainer` attribute in the `@ApiOperation` annotation.

The value `List` will wrap your `WidgetDto` in a container.

```
@ApiOperation(
    value = "Get all widgets.",
    response = WidgetDto.class,
    responseContainer = "List"
)
```